# Elastic Search: value pertaining to a max value with filter

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have documents with the following schema in Elastic Search:

```
{
  "data": {
    "cpu_id": string,
    "cpu_usage": double
  },
  "time": timestamp
}
```

Given a `cpu_id` how do I find the `cpu_usage` at the max `time`?
I've spent a good while trying to figure it out, but haven't made much head way. In SQL it would just be something like:

```
SELECT cpu_usage
FROM cpus
WHERE cpu_id = 1
ORDER BY cpu_ts DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Cheers for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
"size": 1,
"sort": {
  "time": {
    "order": "desc"
  }
},
"query": {
  "filtered": {
    "filter": {
      "term": {
        "data.cpu_id": "1"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you the most recent document (according to the `time` value) that matches `cpu_id = "1"`.

Comment: This returns a `query_parsing_exception` with reason `query malformed, no field after start object`.